# Doubt with Socle and O'Nan-Scott Theorem.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, socle

The following is the statement of O'Nan-Scott Theorem.

**Theorem**: Let $G$ be a finite primitive group of degree $n$, and let $H$ be the socle of G. Then either

(a) $H$ is a regular elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$, $n=p^m:=|H|$, and $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the affine group ${\rm AGL}_m(P)$;  or

(b) H is isomorphic to a direct power $T^m$ of a nonabelian simple group $T$
and one of the following holds:

(i) m = 1 and G is isomorphic to a subgroup of Aut(T);

(ii) $m\geq2$ and $G$ is a group of "diagonal type" with $n = |T|^{m-1}$.

(iii) $m\geq2$ and for some proper divisor $d$ of $m$ and some primitive group $U$ with a socle isomorphic to $T^d$, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the wreath product $U\,\wr\, {\rm Sym}(m/d)$ with the product action, and $n=l^{m/d}$, where $l$ is the degree of $U$.

(iv) $m\geq6$, $H$ is regular, and $n=|T|^m$.

**Question:** In the Case (b), the socle of $G$ which is $H$ is isomorphic to a direct power $T^m$ of a nonabelian simple group $T$. In the case (b)(iii), does any bounds on the order of $H$ in terms of $n$ is known ? (e.g. in part(b)(ii), $|T|^{m-1}=n)$.

Note: Trivial bound is $|H| \leq |G| \leq n^{(\sqrt n)\log n}$. (Thus I am asking about some nontrivial one like $|H|\leq n^c$ or $n^{poly(\log n)}$ ).

**Edit:** See page 126 of the book ["Finite permutation group"](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Permutation_Groups.html?id=4QDpFN6k61EC&redir_esc=y), where it is mentioned that (last line of the first paragraph), the Groups of types (b)(ii) and (b)(iii), are generally distinguished as having a small orders of socle with respect to their degree.

Comment: Use `$\le$` for $\le$.

Comment: I think you want $n = |T|^{m-1}$ rather than $n=|T|^m$ in (b)(ii). In the group $S_m \wr C_2$ in (b)(iii), we have $|H| = (m!)^2$ and $n = m^2$, so there is no bound of the type you are suggesting.

Comment: @DerekHolt,  Here, $H$ is the socle of $G$. It is direct product of non-abelian simple groups.  Do you mean that, in the above example $T \cong A_m$?  Since $T$ can not be $S_m$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I got your notation confused. $T = A_m$, $H = A_m^2$ so $|H| = (m!)^2/4$, , $U = S_m$.

Comment: Okay right. What if we discard the case when $T$ is $A_m$?  I am asking this because I have read somewhere that, Groups of types (b)(ii) and (b)(iii), are generally distinguished as having a small orders of socle with respect to their degree. Added a link for the reference (in the question).

Comment: Sorry once again for the confusion of notation, the $m$ is my comment is different from the $m$ in your question. I am unsure exactly what you are asking now. Do you want to exclude the case when $T$ is isomorphic to $A_k$ for some $k$?

Comment: My question is: can we bound (non-trivial bound which mentioned in the question) the order of socle (i.e. $|T^m|)$ in terms of the degree of $G$ (which is $n$) ?                            If it is not true in general, then for what non abelian simple group $T$ it is true ? Like does it holds if we exclude the case when $T$ is not $A_k$ for some $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 5.6B on Page 167 of Dixon and Mortimer's book states that for any primitive group of degree $n$ other than $A_n$ and $S_n$, we have $|G| \le \exp(c \sqrt{n}(\log n)^2)$ for some constant $c$.

The examples $G=S_k \wr C_2$ with product action, where $k = \sqrt{n}$, that I mentioned in my comment have $|G:H| = 8$ and order greater than $\exp(d \sqrt{n}(\log n)^2)$ for some constant $d$. So we cannot improve on this bound for $|G|$ as a bound for $|H|$.

But if we assume that $T$ is not isomorphic to $A_k$ for any $k$ then, using the classification of finite simple groups, we can use Theorem 5.6C (ii) to get the  better bound of $\exp( b (\log n)^2)$ for $|G|$ and $|H|$, for some constant $b$.

The example $U \wr C_2$ with product action, with $U = {\rm GL}_k(2)$ in its natural primitive action of degree $2^k-1$ shows that this is best possible (apart from estimating the constant $b$).