# Index of Socle of primitive permutation group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, quotient-group, socle

This is a follow up question of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438587/doubt-with-socle-and-onan-scott-theorem)

(**Edit:** The following question is for primitive group $G$ which lies in the case (i) and does not lie in case (ii) of Theorem 5.6C of the textbook ["Finite permutation group"](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Permutation_Groups.html?id=4QDpFN6k61EC&redir_esc=y) (page no. 167))

It is mentioned in Theorem 5.6C(i) that, the socle $H$ is permutation isomorphic to $A_m^d$ for some $d >0 $. Also, the Theorem 5.6B (on the same page) says that, any primitive group has order at most $exp\{c' \sqrt{n}(\log n)^2 \}$.

**Question**  In the case of Theorem 5.6C(i), does the index of $H$ in $G$ have a bound in terms of $n$ (degree of $G$)?
(I mean bound like $|G/H|\leq n^c$ or $n^{poly(\log n)}$ )

Note: I am trying to understand the O'Nan-Scott Theorem and its application. There I came up with the above doubt. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to make your assumptions clearer.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I apologize. I have edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: But Theorem 5.6C does not say that, it says that at least one of conditions (i) and (ii) hold. It does not say that Condition (i) holds. Do you mean you want to assume that Condition (i) holds? If so, then why not say so?

Comment: @DerekHolt, Yes, I am assuming that only Condition (i) holds for $G$.  Because, if for some $G$, Condition (ii) also hold then it solve my doubt in this case, right ?

Comment: I am really just asking you to edit the question so that it makes sense and it is clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I have made it more clear. I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $n \ge m^d$ and $|G:H| \le 2^dd!$, so I guess that gives a bound of $n^{O(\log \log(n))}$.

Comment: I am not able to prove $|G : H| \leq 2^d d!$. Assuming it together with $n \geq m^d$ we can show the bound you mentioned. Is there any reference or hint to prove $|G : H| \leq 2^d d!$ ?

Comment: That;s the order of the outer automorphism group of $A_m^d$ (for $m > 6$).

Comment: I apologize, but still I didn't get it. It will be good if you give some detailed explanation @Derek holt.

Comment: Automorphisms of $A_m^d$ permute the direct factors and there are $d!$ such permutations. The kernel of this permutation action consists of automorphisms that fix all direct factors. Since $|{\rm Aut}((A_n):A_n| = |S_n:A_n| = 2$ for $n \ge 6$, the order of the outer automorphism group induced by the kernel of the permutation action is $2^d$, so $|{\rm Aut}(A_m^d):A_m^d| = 2^dd!$.

Comment: Thank you! It is clear now.